# DbContext.OnConfiguring not getting called and behaving weird in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my asp.net core project i have a `ReadingContext` class derived from `DbContext`. According to documentation `OnConfiguring` should be called for every instance of `DbContext` that is created.

But in my case it is only called when i inspect the instance while debugging. I have a breakpoint inside `OnConfiguring` but it is not hit even when the method is called.

OnConfiguring method.
[image: OnConfiguring method]
.

Instance created but `OnConfiguring` not called yet
[image: Instance created]

.

OnConfiguring called on looking into the object but it's breakpoint didn't hit.
[image: OnConfiguring called]

Comment: Try to create the context just in the constructor of the controller

Comment: I did that.. No difference in the behavior even if i create context manually inside the constructor without using DI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> According to documentation OnConfiguring should be called for every instance of DbContext that is created.

I don't know which documentation you refer to, but I'm sure it doesn't say that `OnConfiguring` runs *when* the context is created. Because it doesn't. It runs whenever a context instance is actually *used* for the first time. That's why you see the method call as soon as you start inspecting the context in the debug view. When you pause on a breakpoint in the debugger, the debugger will never jump to another breakpoint, even when the code is hit.

Contexts are supposed to be created and disposed in large numbers. Therefore, creating a context must be as light-weight as possible. Its internal components are created by lazy initialization as much as possible.

Comment: I don't know whether to call it documentation or what but its written as comments in the DbContext definition inside visual studio.. Even if it is called on first use don't u think it should be called on execution of 'context.TempReadings' inside debug ? (i tried outside debug too) . What is considered as first use?

Comment: `_context.TempReadings` doesn't execute the query yet. `ToList()` will do that. First use (I think) is when the context starts executing SQL commands.

Comment: `_context.TempReadings.ToList()` didn't work either. But it cause exception to be thrown as TempReadings is null which i think should be because context is not configured yet. But `_context.Model` cause OnConfiguring to be called and the breakpoint is also hit instantly before constructor breakpoint. Btw where to find documentation, i couldn't find any explanation about OnConfiguring method. at most i found [this](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html#onconfiguring)

Comment: That documentation is the only official source presently. It doesn't say anything about when exactly these methods run. Looking in EF's source code show these lazy initializations though. Anyway, if `TempReadings` is null, I'm afraid something more fundamental is wrong with your code. A `DbSet` property should never be null, if everything is normal.

Comment: Oh wait, it isn't a property, just a member variable. Add `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: ohh.. never expected i could hv problem there.. thanks a lot.. its working now.. actually i never worked in any previous version of Asp.net and EF.. Im having a lot of trouble bcz of lack of familiarity and documentation.

Comment: Then *maybe* it's better to get familiar with EF 6, which is very stable at the moment and better documented and covered in internet samples etc. EF core is still developing. No breaking changes are expected any more, but at times, it may be hard to distinguish bugs/omissions from features (or the lack thereof).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else had this issue, I had to use an empty constructor to get OnConfiguring called:

```
public ReadingContext() : base()
{

}
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder  
optionsBuilder)
{
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", 
    optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
  config = builder.Build();  
  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString
    ("ReadingContextConnection"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this post is old and seems to be with EF Core v1.0.0. I am facing same issue with EF Core v3.1.100 even after adding empty constructor. I could step-into DbContext() and other methods but OnConfiguring()!!

```
    public SchoolContext() : base()
    { 
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(local)\MYSQL;Initial Catalog=School; Integrated Security=True;");
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16479 fixed the issue, Its related to lazy loading! It's enabled by default. Setting it to false works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my scenario (*trivial, but was overlooked*):

1. My context was built by the Scaffolding process
2. I have a parent context that my scaffolded context needs to inherit.  The parent context provide the default OnConfiguring() mechanism
3. I need to remove the OnConfiguring() in my scaffolded context in order for the parent's OnConfiguring() to be called...pretty trivial OO.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this; my case was a little different. I had derived a DC, and OnConfiguring() was firing in my subclass, but not in the base. Had one of those SMH moments when I realized I just need to add a call to the `base` member in the subclasses:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(options);
        // subclass specific code
    }
```