# EntityFramework core `OnConfiguring` not being called on initialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days now and I am still unable to figure out why this might be happening. I am creating a new instance of EntityFramework `DbContext` and the method `OnConfiguring` is not being called. I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058739/dbcontext-onconfiguring-not-getting-called-and-behaving-weird-in-asp-net-core) and unfortunately that does not help.
This is an outline of my code

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext()
            : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            int a = 12;       
        }

    }
```

This is how I am calling it from my controller in ASP.net

```
MyContext b = new MyContext();
```

However `OnConfiguring` is not being called. I am using EntityFramework core 2.2.4 nuget package.
Any suggestions on things that I can try ? that might help me narrow down this issue ?

Comment: Just use Scaffold-Dbcontext command. It will auto generate everything for you.

Comment: Scroll down until you see "Scaffold-DbContext" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell I posted answer below as well. Can check.

Comment: The post you mentioned said that it's not executing on object creation but during your first query. Is it not true in your case?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras nope it does not hit the breakpoint or anything in `OnConfiguring`

Comment: It has to be called at some later point. For instance, if you add `_ = b.ChangeTracker;` after `MyContext b = new MyContext();`, it should be called at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You better use Scaffold-DbContext to generate everything automatically for you. You need to download 4 from nugets

1) EntityFrameworkCore

2) EntityFrameworkCore.Design

3) EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

4) EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Open Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. And enter this below in console.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourserveraddress;Database=yourdatabase;user id=youruser;password=yourpassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "YourOwnContext"
```