# DB Context not getting correct connection string what is the issue here

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to diagnose an issue inside my db context configuration however its never going hit a brake point there as this is when I issue the
dotnet ef update command. For Example I want some way to debug what is in the I am using ef 7 and .net 7

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    var test2 = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    options.UseSqlServer(test2);
    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
}
```

This is my context

```
public class StubsDBContext :IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
      private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
      public StubsDBContext()
       {

       }

        public StubsDBContext(DbContextOptions<StubsDBContext> options , IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public DbSet<Stub> Stubs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stub> Stubs3 { get; set; }

        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            var test2 = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            options.UseSqlServer(test2);

            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
```

I add it from my program.cs as such at this point test does retrieve the correct connection string

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
        string? TEST = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<StubsDBContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(TEST,
           builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(StubsDBContext).Assembly.FullName)));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StubsDBContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        return services;
}
```

Appsettings

```
 {

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "removed for security"

  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "AppSettings": {
      "Secret": "removed for security"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my program .cs

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var config = provider.GetService<IConfiguration>();


        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
       .Build();

        builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);
     //+   builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
       
        // Add services to the container.
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        var appSettingsSection = config.GetSection("AppSettings");
        


        builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();


...removed for length
}
```

Comment: Pls share us more error details.

Comment: Please re read the question and get back to me ! It cleary states when doing migrations its not working unless a hard code the connection string but I cannot place debug points inside OnConfiguring to see the value of test2 !!! As OnConfiguring does not excute in the normal programming since it applied when you run dotnet ef update

Comment: What happened when we remove this ` _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
       .Build();` ?

Comment: @JasonPan THAT is required to tell the calling assebmly the location of the appsettings.json file without that it wont funciton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running dotnet ef update command, it will execute `OnConfiguring`, but it will not hit the breakpoint.

You can output `test2` to the console and you can see its value:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    var test2 = _configuration.GetConnectionString("StubsDBContextConnection");
    Console.WriteLine(test2);
    options.UseSqlServer(test2);
    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
}
```

[image]

You can hit this breakpoint when you are using the context instance. For example, to manipulate the database in the controller:

```
_context.Stubs.Add(xxx);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

[image]

Please check [explanation by Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059083/18789859).

Comment: Makes total since when i think about it thanks